# identify movie about alien spreading disease

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, alien-invasion

I watched this movie long time ago. This is what I remember:

- I watched it around early 2000's
- The alien is spreading blood-like mark disease/virus.
- The  alien ship is crash landing on land
- There's a scene in which a chopper shooting the crashed alien ship
- There's a main antagonist but I can't remember his/her name.

That's what I remember. I think it's horror, but maybe not.

Comment: I watched it  in the early 2000's (it's a long time ago, isn't it?). No, not taking photograph i believe. The alien ship is crash landing on land.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be movie version of Stephen King's "Dreamcatcher"?

2003, crash-landed alien ship, red fungal plague that looks blood-like. If you meant "chopper", that's in there too...and there's a couple antagonists, but the main one is an alien body thief known as "Mr. Grey" who is trying to spread the aforementioned red plague.

Comment: This could be it. I'll confirm it as soon as I see the trailer. Thank you.